# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My custom filter is giving me an error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

code :

```
angular.module('PatientApp', []).filter('ageFilter', function() {
     // birthday is a date
     function calculateAge(birthday) { 
         var dateOut = new Date(birthday);
         dateOut.setDate(dateOut.getDate() + 1);
         var ageDifMs = Date.now() - dateOut .getTime();
         // miliseconds from epoch
         var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); 
         return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
     }
     return function(birthdate) { 
           return calculateAge(birthdate);
     }; 
});
```

Comment: And what is your question? Is the error not clear?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me. Without more detail it is hard to reproduce the error. But your filter code seems correct.

```
angular.module('PatientApp', []).filter('ageFilter', function() {
     // birthday is a date
     function calculateAge(birthday) { 
         var dateOut = new Date(birthday);
         dateOut.setDate(dateOut.getDate() + 1);
         var ageDifMs = Date.now() - dateOut .getTime();
         // miliseconds from epoch
         var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); 
         return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
     }
     return function(birthdate) { 
           return calculateAge(birthdate);
     }; 
})
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $filter){
  var ageFilter = $filter('ageFilter');
  $scope.age = ageFilter('12/25/1995');
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uegoSEWJgqnMCI1ZzPCk?p=preview